# Why is my function not printing the area of a pentagon?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a function that will return the area of a pentagon, but it just prints 0 to the screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double area_of_pentagon(int side){

  double area = 1/4 * sqrt(5*(5+2*sqrt(5)))*side*side;

  return area;
  
}

int main(){

  std::cout << area_of_pentagon(6);
  
}
```

My code is supposed to output 61.94 if the side length is 6, but it just returns 0.

Comment: 1/4 is 0. Look up integer division in C++. You might want to try `(double)1/4` to get floating point division.

Comment: Or use the literal `0.25`

Comment: This is integer division:  1/4 is (1 div 4) = 0; 1%4 is (1 mod 4) = 1; real number division would be 1.0/4 = 0.25

Comment: Thank you. So from my understanding, integer division in c++ discards the remainder? In this case 1/4 would be 0.25, but c++ discards the .25 correct?

Comment: @asvalk1672 more importantly, the result of integer division is an integer.  But an integer undergoes an implicit conversion to double if multiplied by a double (result of sqrt is a double)  Left to right evaluation means 1/4 are both integers at the time of division, the converted to 0.0 to be multiplied by the sqrt (giving 0.0).  and the `side` is converted to double to be multiplied by the 0.0 -- happens twice.  Same precedence operators are evaluated left to right, my friend.

Comment: The result of the division (as well as any other operator or function) depends on the *types* of the values it is applied to; since 1 and 4 are integers the result is the integer division 'div', which is mathematically defined to be 0; if you want to apply the real numbers division, you have to indicate somehow that the operands (at least one of them) are floating point values: 1.0/4 or (double)1/4

Comment: Oops. Actually, you tagged C++ and the (double) is a C style cast whose use is discouraged in C++. 1.0/4 is fine for both. If you had two int variables instead of literals, the C++ style cast would be static_cast<double>( variable ).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double area_of_pentagon(int side){

  //double area = 1/4 * sqrt(5*(5+2*sqrt(5)))*side*side; // 1/4 is 0 which is causing problem
    //Use below 2 options.
  double area = (sqrt(5*(5+2*sqrt(5)))*side*side)/4;
  //double area = (0.25) * sqrt(5*(5+2*sqrt(5)))*side*side; //or use this
  return area;
  
}

int main(){

  std::cout << area_of_pentagon(6);
  
}
```

Comment: One suggestion would be to try and debug this kind of problem by checking output step by step. I did not got time to check the comments posted on your problem earlier but they have already beautifully explained the RC. Happy Learning !

Comment: Do you have any idea how to find the root cause by debugging? As far as I know, debuggers evaluate entire lines, so it will go from `1/4*sqrt(...)`, directly to `0`, and it would be very beneficial for the author to see the intermediate step `0*sqrt(...)`. Is there a debugger which performs such kind of "inline" calculations?